# How to solve this limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\,{{\left( \frac{{{u}_{n}}}{{{v}_{n}}} \right)}^{2040}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$ be positive numerical sequences such that $(1+\sqrt{2})^n=u_n+v_n\sqrt{2}$  with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ 
How to determine the limit of 
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( \frac{{{u}_{n}}}{{{v}_{n}}} \right)}^{2040}}$$

I start think to find such recessive sequence for $u_n$ terms in order to separate them using induction but this leads to nothing . so as result is there any shortcut to attack this problem?

Comment: $u_n$ and $v_n$ are integers ? Otherwise you can have a lot of possibilities for the limit.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe agreed , the question must mention $u_n$ and $v_n$ be integer or not, otherwise the question seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** [The fact is that, as @TheSilverDoe has mentioned, $u_n$ and $v_n$ are undertermined without additional conditions given. It is typically assumed that $u_n, v_n$ are integers in this kind of problems, so I will just presume this.] Note that $(1-\sqrt{2})^n=u_n-v_n\sqrt{2}$. Thus
$$
u_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2},\quad v_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt 2}.
$$ Now, you may be able to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{u_n}{v_n}\right]^{2040}$.

Comment: sorry first line is not clear to me

Comment: First line has absolutely no reason to be true, except in the case (non-mentioned in the question) where $u_n$ and $v_n$ are both integers.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, you are right. Without some other constraints, $u_n$ and $v_n$ are undetermined. But I didn't care much about it because in this kind of problem, it is typically assumed that $u_n$ and $v_n$ are integers. Most likely, the OP just missed that condition.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,1)$ is a solution of the following [Pell like](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=616&lmm=0) equation (or rather [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation)).
$$x^2-2y^2=-1$$ 
but then
$$\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)=-1 \Rightarrow
\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n=(-1)^n \Rightarrow \\
\left(u_n+v_n\sqrt{2}\right)\left(u_n-v_n\sqrt{2}\right)=(-1)^n \Rightarrow
u_n^2-2v_n^2=(-1)^n$$
$(u_n,v_n)$ are integers (easy to show using [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)). So
$$\left(\frac{u_n}{v_n}\right)^2=2+\frac{(-1)^n}{v_n^2} \iff 
\left(\frac{u_n}{v_n}\right)^{2040}=\left(2+\frac{(-1)^n}{v_n^2}\right)^{1020}$$
We also have
$$v_n =\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{2}}\Rightarrow
v_n^2=\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}-2\cdot(-1)^n}{8}$$
and

- $0<3-2\sqrt{2}<1 \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}=0$
- $3+2\sqrt{2}>1 \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}=+\infty$

as a result (and because $f(x)=x^{1020}$ is continuous)
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{u_n}{v_n}\right)^{2040}=
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(2+\frac{(-1)^n}{v_n^2}\right)^{1020}=\left(2+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{v_n^2}\right)^{1020}=2^{1020}$$

Comment: i know its just that this was an exam question and i need to know if i was wrong solving it that way hmm

Comment: Here come the downvoters leaving no comments ...

Comment: @rtybase I think the downvote comes from the fact that you are making asumptions that are not made in the original question. Otherwise your answer is not true : for example, for $u_n = (1+ \sqrt{2})^n - \sqrt{2}$ and $v_n = 1$, the limit is obviously $+\infty$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe that's a problem with the question. My answer clearly states <<Pell like>> which is in integers and is a good assumption (because, otherwise, as you stated, there is no good answer to this question).

Comment: Yes, I understood that, I am just saying that the downvote probably comes from that.

Comment: Well, in absence of a comment, sadly, we will never know ...

Comment: @rtybase I didn't down vote, but it may be due to a mistake. As Song states in his answer, $(1-\sqrt{2})^n=u_n-v_n\sqrt{2}$, but you have $(-1+\sqrt{2})^n=-u_n+v_n\sqrt{2}$ which is only true for odd $n$. Thus, for example, $(\sqrt{2}+1)^2 = 3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ and $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2 = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$, giving $u_2 = 3$ and $v_2 = 2$, but then $2v_2^2 - u_2^2 = -1$, not $1$ as you state. I believe the correct result is $u_n^2 - 2v_n^2 = (-1)^n$.  Please check to confirm this. It'll change some of the rest of your answer, but as far as I can tell, your result will still be the same.

Comment: Thank you @JohnOmielan! Yes, that was an unforgivable mistake :( ... fixed now.

Comment: @rtybase (+1) Now it seems to be correct, except you forgot to use the $(-1)^n$ in $2$ places as the numerator over $v_n^2$ in your last line.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yep, I did. Thank you one more time!